# Double quotes in VF Page help text

Tags: visualforce

I need to include a custom help text which includes double quotes like this=
To claim materials, use checkbox labeled “Claim as shown".

Vf Code

```
 <c:FormFields label="Claim as Shown" rendered="{!if(check == 'Yes',true,false)}" isHelpText="true" showHelpMethod="true" helpText="To claim materials, use checkbox labeled &quot;Claim as shown&quot;.">
```

Any idea how to display quotations within help text?
The custom message is shown as below in VF page:-
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the VF code here so that we can identify the problem and then provide the best suitable and best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can use two single quotes.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:outputPanel layout="inline">Test "text"</apex:outputPanel>
    <br/>
    <c:testcomp helpText="To claim materials, use checkbox labeled ''Claim as shown''" />
</apex:page>
```

Visualforce component:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="helpText" type="String" description="The variable to represent a single account in the iteration."/>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="inline">{! helpText }</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

Result (in Google Chrome):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This one has resolved the issue without any additional code.Nice workaround

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure which tag you are using on VF page to display the help text but you can use `escape="false"` to display the double quotes.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!message}" escape="false" />
<apex:pageMessages escape="false" ></apex:pageMessages>
```

In controller

```
message = 'To claim materials, use checkbox labeled “Claim as shown".';
apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Info, 'To claim materials, use checkbox labeled “Claim as shown".'));
```

[image]

Comment: Downvotes without comments will not help anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion. I am planning to use this approach in next phase of our work process. I tried using the above code for this one piece and it worked as well.